# Rect JS installation issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to react js, I have installed node js stable version. I have checked the node version and npm version it's working fine,  I have tried to install react using   "npm init react -app " &  "npx create-react-app" but I'm getting an error  I have tried all the suggestions  (even I have uninstalled my anti-virus scanner) but it's not working. can anyone please help.

(Error screen shot  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/17uWV6RX_e-ev-Afs5r4viqKTOL-SDsyY/view?usp=sharing")

Comment: You can't install react with the command "npm init react -app"

Comment: Check this https://flaviocopes.com/react-create-react-app/  once.It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install node.js
2) Install npm by: 
         install npm –g
3) Create react app: 
        npx create-react-app test-app

Navigate to folder by:
 cd test-app

Hope this will work.

Comment: When using npm tooling you should be use cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux (win10) in my opinion.